# Use of Pointers for string handling in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, swap

I am learning the basics of C++. The code is working fine as I wanted, but what I want to know is in **case 2** where the function is to swap the strings, what is basically going on? Is the string at **array[pos1 -1]** being copied to  **temp** and then swapped or just the addresses of the strings to be swapped are being reallocated?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   const char *array[] {"Albert",
                        "Newton",
                        "Gallilio",
                        "Hawking"};

   cout << "What do you want to do:\n1-Display Strings\n2-Swap Positions" << endl;
   unsigned short int choice{};
   cin >> choice;

   switch (choice)
   {
    case 1:
    {
    for (short int i = 0; i < _countof(array); i++)
    {
        cout << "\n" << array[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
    break;
    }
    case 2: 
    {
    short int pos1{}, pos2{};
    const char *temp{ nullptr };

    cout << "Whom do you want to swap? Enter two numbers when prompted: " << endl;
    cout << "Swap --- "; cin >> pos1;
    cout << "With --- "; cin >> pos2;

    temp = array[pos1 - 1];
    array[pos1 - 1] = array[pos2 - 1];
    array[pos2 - 1] = temp;

    cout << "\nChanged Order is";

    for (short int i{} ; i < _countof(array); i++)
    {
        cout << "\n" << array[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
    break;
    }
    default:
    cout << "\a";
  }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The latter; `temp` and the elements of `array` are pointers, so that swap operation just swaps the addresses of the strings.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Instead of using arrays of `char` as strings you should prefer `std::string`. That is easier to handle and less error prone (e.g. with regard to buffer overflows, memory management, etc.).

Comment: Got it! Thanks folks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume `pos1` is 1 and `pos2` is 2.

Then `array[pos1-1]` holds a pointer to a character `A` that is interpreted as a string of characters `Albert\0` terminated by a null. Likewise `array[pos2-1]` holds a pointer to the string `Newton\0`.

When `case 2` is hit, `temp` is initialized to hold a null pointer. Then `temp` is assigned to hold a copy of the pointer to `Albert\0`. Then `array[pos1-1]` is reassigned to hold a pointer to `Newton\0`. We then want `array[pos2-1]` to point to `Albert\0`, but the pointer value in `array[pos1-1]` doens't point there anymore. That's where the copy in temp comes in, because it is still a pointer to `Albert\0`, so this pointer is copied to `array[pos2-1]`.

Comment: Helped a lot! Thanks a bunch!